# Why doesn't Hood shoot Chayton?

Tags: banshee

In *Banshee* Season 3, episode 5, "Tribal", Chayton and his Redbones stage a siege on the Banshee police station.

Near the end of the battle:

> Lucas enters the Cadi to find Chayton holding Siobhan captive. He holds Chayton at gunpoint but is reluctant to pull the trigger because of Siobhan and instead he puts his gun down and pleads for Chayton to leave the girl out of their affairs. One of the Redbones approaches from rear and hits Lucas on the head with a steel bar. Lucas falls to the floor, incapacitated, and looks on helplessly and dizziness as Chayton taunts him and then snaps poor Siobhan's neck. Then Lucas passes out from a hit.

Now this confused me, because Chayton stood head and shoulders - literally - above Siobhan.  Hood was about 4 metres away, and he's a good enough shot that he could have easily shot Chayton through the head.

I don't buy this:

> reluctant to pull the trigger because of Siobhan and instead he puts his gun down

Why did he cave and put the gun down?  Hood has shown in the past that he prefers to take direct action to end any threat to him or others.  There's no way Chayton could beat the gun in that scenario; Hood had a clear and easy shot, and all the justification in the world.

**Why didn't Hood shoot Chayton?**

Comment: Good question. I guess out of universe the writers wanted to explore the later episodes where Hood goes after him.